# How do I access paintComponent() from another class in Java?

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel, extends

So, I have my main class which extends `JFrame`, and I have a second class which extends `JPanel` to allow `paintComponent` to draw on the `JPanel`. But how do I access the new class to paint onto the `JPanel`?

Here is my code:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.border.*;

public class MTGSAMPServerReference extends JFrame implements ActionListener {
    public static Toolkit tk = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit(); 
    static int ScrnWidth = ((int) tk.getScreenSize().getWidth());
    static int ScrnHeight = ((int) tk.getScreenSize().getHeight());
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private static JList list1;
    private static JButton next;
    private static JPanel bg = new JPanel();

    public MTGSAMPServerReference() {
        // set flow layout for the frame
        this.getContentPane().setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEADING));
        Object[]mainData = {"Vehicles", "Bikes/Bicycles", "Boats", "Houses", "Businesses", "Objects", "Jobs", "Ranks", "Licenses", "VIP"};
        JPanel controls = new JPanel(new BorderLayout(5,5));
        list1 = new JList<Object>(mainData);
        list1.setVisibleRowCount(10);
        next = new JButton("Next");
        next.addActionListener(this);
        controls.add(new JScrollPane(list1));
        controls.add(next, BorderLayout.PAGE_END);
        controls.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(25,25,0,0));
        add(controls);
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        if (e.getActionCommand().equals("Next")) {
            int index = list1.getSelectedIndex();
            System.out.println("Index Selected: " + index);
            String s = (String) list1.getSelectedValue();
            System.out.println("Value Selected: " + s);
        }
    }

    public void createAndShowGUI() {
        //Create and set up the window.
        JFrame f = new MTGSAMPServerReference();
        //Display the window.
        f.pack();
        f.setVisible(true);
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        f.setSize(1200, 800);
        f.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        list1.setSize(250, 250);
        list1.setLocation(0, 0);
        next.setSize(75, 25);
        next.setLocation(251, 276);
        MTGSAMPServerReference.this.repaint();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
            MTGSAMPServerReference gui = new MTGSAMPServerReference();
            gui.createAndShowGUI();
            }
        });
    }
}

class drawOnPanel extends JPanel {
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D)g;
        g2.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
        g2.drawRect(0, 0, 50, 50);
    }
}
```

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Oh, the layout problem solved!

Comment: You seem to be on a mission to get the online community to write your app for you. What is this app? I've seen several posts related to it.

Comment: @tbodt No, I am just trying to learn, when I run into a problem, I google it, do some research, and see what I can do on my own. When I hit a wall, I ask for help. Lately though it's been more than a wall, but more of a tower :l I just need to be able to get past this obstacle and then I should be golden!

Comment: What is this app your writing anyway? `MTGSAMPServerReference` isn't much of a hint.

Comment: It is a big reference guide for a community I am a part of. More of an interactive guide.

Comment: And MTGSAMPServerReference tells everything about the program. MTG is a community, SAMP is a mod for a game, and finally a reference for the server.

Comment: If the size of the custom rendering is not expected to change, it is simpler to draw direct to a `BufferedImage` and display it in a `JLabel`.  Is the size of the rendered part expected to change?

Comment: I don't expect it to change, but it is going to act as a "container" to hold information

Comment: a) don't do any manual sizing/locating of components, **ever** - that's the task of the LayoutManager b) please learn java naming conventions and stick to them

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just add the panel as you would any other component. The `paintComponent` method is called when it is time for a repaint.

Comment: How do I access it from a different class though?

Comment: Why do you want it to be accessed from another class? You would have it called by containers to paint it.

Comment: Did you look at my code?

Comment: I can only extend one class at a time, thus the need for a new class to extend `JPanel`

Comment: Yes, I did. What exactly do you want to accomplish with this panel?

Comment: I want to attach the panel to the frame to allow me to draw on the panel.

Comment: If you want to paint the panel into the frame, follow my advice. Just add it as you would any other component. There is no need to call `paintComponent` directly. In fact you should never call it directly. If it needs repainting, call `panel.repaint()` instead. `paintComponent` will be invoked as soon as possible.

Comment: But when I run my program, it is not drawing my rectangle.

Comment: Are you adding an instance of the panel to the frame? That's essential. If you are, then tell me exactly what is not working.

Comment: All of my code I have already posted.

Comment: You didn't change your code? You need to add a instance of the panel to the frame.

Answer (score 3):

You didn't add the `drawOnPanel` class to the container of the frame. add this line:

```
add(new drawOnPanel());
```

---

**Additional notes**:

1. Inside `createAndShowGUI()`, your class already extended from `JFrame`, there is no need to create another `JFrame` object, change it to:

   ```
      public void createAndShowGUI() {
       //Create and set up the window.
       //JFrame f = new MTGSAMPServerReference();
       //Display the window.

       setVisible(true);
       setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
       setSize(1200, 800);
       setLocationRelativeTo(null);
       list1.setSize(250, 250);
       list1.setLocation(0, 0);
       next.setSize(75, 25);
       next.setLocation(251, 276);
       repaint();
       pack();
   }
   ```
2. Pick the `pack()` method to the end after repaint to fit the size for the components as I did in above.

@knorberg's comment: *Where and how does this draw my rectangle?*

Your drawing is good, just Override`getPreferredSize()` method inside the `drawOnPanel` class:

```
class drawOnPanel extends JPanel {
  @Override
  protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D)g;
        g2.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
        g2.drawRect(0, 0, 50, 50);
    }
  @Override
  public Dimension getPreferredSize(){
    return new Dimension(200,200);
  }
}
```

Comment: Where and how does this draw my rectangle? `g2.drawRect(0, 0, 50, 50);`

Comment: And, I have been told never to draw on a JFrame, but to use a JPanel.

Comment: @knorberg: Your drawing is good, just Override` getPreferredSize()` method inside the `drawOnPanel` class and set some dimension for it, if you don't know that, I will update my answer.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. Can explain a little more?

Comment: @knorberg:See the updated answer.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels I have NOT been ignoring questions AT ALL! I have been marking them as answered. Don't accuse me. I am here to get help and for me to be accused is uncalled for. This is supposed to be a helpful community.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels I have responded to answers. They answer partially, but not completely. AND they tell me to make a new thread. I don't come here to get criticized by the community. I come here to get help. So if you are not here to help, then I will kindly ask you to please leave.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels And I appreciate that, but when you call me ignorant and criticize me on something other than my code, I will not tolerate it. If you are not here to make constructive efforts to help then please leave.